# encode/decode CDRs according to the ASN.1 syntax specification

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

I have XXX.asn  file and YYYY.dat CDR (encoded with XXX.asn) file. I want to parse this YYYY.dat file to human readable format. Is there any simple example to parse BER encoded file using asn structure file in java using Bouncy Castle api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that many .dat files containing CDRs have non-ASN.1 headers at the beginning of the .dat file and also have non-ASN.1 separators between each CDR record.  You need to verify the format of the .dat file to determine which portion of it actually contains BER encoded data before trying to use any ASN.1 Tool to decode the CDR records.  Some commercial ASN.1 Utilities have built in the ability to recognize these non-ASN.1 separators in CDR data files.  Please try to download a free trial of the OSS ASN-1Step Utility from [OSS Nokalva, Inc.](http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-download.html) (the company I work for) to see if the .dat file has just BER data or contains the non-BER headers and separators that many of these .dat files contain.

Answer (score 0):

If CDR file has non ASN.1 defined separators between each ASN.1 encoded CDR object, you need to read it as binary data to get clean ASN.1 encoded data stream by splitting and removing the separators and/or headers. Once clean ASN.1 encoded data generated, you can easily decode using bouncycastle ASN.1 API and get array of CDR data objects.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128713/10095046) is the java ASN.1 decoder sample for the original SO question.